# How generate javadoc with Gradle?

Tags: java, android, gradle, build, javadoc

I would like generate javadoc out of aar lib file, but my actual task not work and finish with error. I'm somewhat lost with gradle.

Where should generate javadocs?

```
android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->

    // This part is for change AAR location
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        def outputFile = output.outputFile
        if (outputFile != null && outputFile.name.endsWith('.aar')) {
            def fileName = "${archivesBaseName}-${version}.aar"
            output.outputFile = new File("$rootProject.projectDir/build/generated-aar", fileName)
        }
    }

    // Here generate tasks for variant to generate Javadocs
    task "generate${variant.name.capitalize()}Javadoc"(type: Javadoc) {
        description = "Generates javadoc for build $variant.name"
        destinationDir = new File("$rootProject.projectDir/build/generated-javadoc", variant.baseName)

        // add SDK classes
        source = variant.javaCompiler.source

        ext.androidJar = "${android.sdkDirectory}/platforms/${android.compileSdkVersion}/android.jar"
        classpath = files(variant.javaCompiler.classpath.files) + files(ext.androidJar)

        ext.androidDoc = "${android.sdkDirectory}/docs/reference"

        options.linksOffline("http://d.android.com/reference", ext.androidDoc)
        options.links("http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/")
        options.links("http://d.android.com/reference/")

        exclude '*BuildConfig.java'
        exclude '*R.java'
        exclude '*impl*'
        exclude '*tests*'
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could add the error that causes the build to fail?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you are following standard project structure then use:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

javadoc {
    source = sourceSets.main.allJava
    classpath = configurations.compile
}
```

If not then you need to specify the `include` closure. Add the closure like:

```
include 'path/to/directory/*'
```

If include closure is not working then add `sourceSet` closure with `srcDir` pointing to the `module/java` directory:

```
sourceSets {
    build {
        java.srcDir file('src/main/java')

    }
}
```

And after that run `$gradle javadoc` command.
Then check your build directory for html files having all javadocs.
Note: Replace **srcDir** with your root package path.

Comment: I've use android.library plugin and maven plugin.

Comment: I try `include **/*.java` but without results

Comment: I'm not sure if the classpath field is necessary anymore. One thing to note is that the java-library plugin has the javadoc tasks available. You can also look [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.javadoc.Javadoc.html) for the updated specifications since the `configurations.compile` option is being deprecated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72952400/gradle-skipping-task-groovydoc-as-it-has-no-source-files-and-no-previous-ou - I'm facing a similar problem with groovydoc.. can you please take a look?

Comment: As suggested by @jsohpetit, only including: `plugins { id 'java' }` and ` `javadoc {     source = sourceSets.main.allJava }` worked for me. The `classpath = ..` line resulted in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69044250/7437143) error. Thank you for sharing your solution!