# Build Gradle Error Could not get unknown property 'compile'

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

i have react native porject when run android this error showed

Build file 'C:\dev\icnet_final\android\app\build.gradle' line: 213

A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Could not get unknown property 'compile' for configuration container of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfigurationContainer.

Answer (score 177, accepted):

If this happens after Gradle upgrade, replace `compile` with `implementation`

Comment: Note that this must also be done for the line with BUCK configuration, i.e. changing `configurations.compile` to `configurations.implementation`!

Comment: This did clear the specific error for me, but I had subsequent issues with java versions. I ended out using [disconnectionist's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69075790/4109824) - insetad of upgrading from `4.2.1` to `7.0.3` I only upgraded to `4.2.2`.

Comment: it should be `runtimeClasspath` and not `implementation`.

Comment: about `configurations.implementation`: `Resolving dependency configuration 'implementation' is not allowed as it is defined as 'canBeResolved=false'.`

Comment: where do i change compile to implementation ?

Comment: @joaoricardotg did you ever find out?

Comment: @Ryker Unfortunately no.

Comment: @joaoricardotg it's in `app/build.gradle` in the `copyDownloadableDepsToLibs` task

Comment: Just comment the line where this appear:
// compile.exclude group: 'com.google.android'

Comment: `implementation` worked for me. I had to edit the files in these two paths. `ROOT/android/app/build.gradle` & `ROOT/node-modules/react-native-os/android/build.gradle`

Comment: See for canBeResolved issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/51924223/432903

Answer (score 33):

I got this error because I upgraded to the latest version of Gradle. I suggest not doing this yet, until React Native has been updated to work with it.

I changed my version of Gradle in `android/build.gradle` to the old version and the project built again. This version now works for me:

```
    classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2')
```

Comment: saved my day.. it should be most accepted answer

Comment: So downgrading from gradle 7 to 4 is an acceptable answer :(

Comment: @mikegross - same here, I reverted my `4.2.1 => 7.0.3` upgrade down to just `4.2.1 => 4.2.2`. It was much less painful.

Comment: After a night of digging, here you saved my life, thanks!

Comment: Remember: if something wrong or weird -- use `expo eject`.

Answer (score 14):

**go to /Users/...../Documents/projectName/android/app/build.gradle**

and

replace **compile** with **implementation**

```
configurations.compile => configurations.implementation
```

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that the gradle task is trying to compile some java code, you have to replace `configurations.compile` with `configurations.compileClasspath`. It points out to the list of dependencies that the JDK requires to compile the java code.

This exception is being thrown from gradle 7+ which does not recognize the property 'compile' any more as it requires the use of ['implementation' or 'api'](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html) according to the case.

If the *.class* files are already available, `configurations.runtimeClasspath` should also work, as it points out to the already compiled java code.

Answer (score 1):

RN 0.64.1
For the dependence, I use

```
    classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0')
```

and for the wrapper

```
    distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-all.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to modify the app/build.gradle file by updating the code below

```
from configurations.compile
```

to

```
from configurations.implementation
```