# Gradle : Skipping task ':groovydoc' as it has no source files and no previous output files

Tags: groovy, groovydoc

I'm trying to create groovydoc using gradle. I have created the below task :
The groovy classes are present in - src/integration-test/groovy/com/x/folders/*.groovy
This is my sourcesets :

```
sourceSets {
    integrationTestCompile {
        java {
            compileClasspath += main.output + test.output
            runtimeClasspath += main.output + test.output
            srcDirs = ['src/integration-test/groovy']
        }
        resources.srcDir file('src/integration-test/resources')
    }
}


    groovydoc {
    source = sourceSets.integrationTestCompile.java.srcDirs
    classpath = configurations.compile
    include '**/com/x/common/controllers/*'
}
```

I get the below message :

```
> Task :groovydoc NO-SOURCE
Skipping task ':groovydoc' as it has no source files and no previous output files.
```

I may have wrongly entered the sourcesets, but I have tried different ways but still getting the very same error message.

Comment: If you're using the groovy plugin (which I assume you are as you're compiling groovy), then you already have the groovydoc task AFAIK

Comment: @tim_yates I was able to make some progress, hence I have updated my question. Can you please help me with this?